# Hide border of window, if i know a handle of this window

Tags: c++, winapi, com, ole

I have already OLE Embedded object Excel Chart. And, when I create this object, i have some problem in project, when I'm resizing window. Using Spy++ I see two process: Excel 7 and Excel 9. Excel 9 contain "trash" in right part, and when I resizing window I can see undefined behaviour.
On the following picture you can see a border, which I want to hide.
[image]

How I can hide this border, if I known handle of window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using [SetWindowLong()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I don't know if the effect is going to be what you are looking for.

```
SetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_TOPMOST);
ShowWindow(win_handle, SW_SHOW);
```