# How to display an image in full screen borderless window in openCV

Tags: c, image, winapi, opencv

I want to display an image in OpenCV in a full screen borderless window.
In other words, only the image pixels will appear, without menu, toolbar, or window background.

Using `imshow()` or `cvShowImage()` don't enable it:

1. The window grows to be full screen
   in width but not in height. It misses few pixels.
2. I could not make it borderless even by changing settings of window
   handler.

I think that the problem is rooted in `cvNamedWindow()` method which creates main `WS_OVERLAPPED` window, then creates a child and all functions like `imshow()` or `cvGetWindowHandle()` operate on the child.

Thus even windows command:

```
SetWindowLong((HWND)cvGetWindowHandle(winName), GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_POPUP);
```

Doesnt help, since the child cannot become borderless `WS_POPUP`. Someone got a workaround?

- Maybe, showing opencv mat to window
  without using opencv built in methods
- Or some kind of windows trick

P.S. I tried the following code:

```
cvMoveWindow("AAA",0,0);
cvSetWindowProperty("AAA", CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

// Also I tried this:
HWND hwnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle("AAA");
RECT windowRect;
windowRect.left = 0;
windowRect.top = 0;
windowRect.right = cxScreen; //Display resolution
windowRect.bottom = cyScreen; //Display resolution
AdjustWindowRect(&windowRect,WS_VISIBLE,false);
long p_OldWindowStyle = SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE,WS_POPUP);
SetWindowPos(hwnd,HWND_TOP,0,0,windowRect.right,windowRect.bottom,SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_POPUP);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you issued `cvShowImage()` to display the window? Because it seems you are not doing it. Anyway, you might want to call the win32 API for this instead, so add a call to `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);` after `SetWindowPos()`.

If your current call to `SetWindowPos()` doesn't do the trick, check this answer: [Hide border of window, if i know a handle of this window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788115/hide-border-of-window-if-i-know-a-handle-of-this-window/5795633#5795633)

I recommend you doing your tests without calling `cvSetWindowProperty()` at first, just to make sure you can find a method that works.

Just a note, if you check `modules/highgui/src/window_w32.cpp` you can see how OpenCV creates windows on Windows.

**EDIT**:

The following code implements the tips I gave before and bypasses the problems the OP reported. The trick is NOT using `cvGetWindowHandle()` to retrieve the windows' handle and use directly *win32* API for that: `FindWindow()`

```
IplImage* cv_img = cvLoadImage("test.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
if(!cv_img)
{
    printf("Failed cvLoadImage\n");
    return -1;
}

cvNamedWindow("main_win", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvMoveWindow("main_win", 0, 0);
cvSetWindowProperty("main_win", CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

cvShowImage("main_win", cv_img);

//HWND cv_hwnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle("main_win");
//if (!cv_hwnd)
//{
//  printf("Failed cvGetWindowHandle\n");
//}
//printf("cvGetWindowHandle returned %p\n", *cv_hwnd);

HWND win_handle = FindWindow(0, L"main_win");
if (!win_handle)
{
    printf("Failed FindWindow\n");
}

SetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_TOPMOST);
ShowWindow(win_handle, SW_SHOW);

cvWaitKey(0);

cvReleaseImage(&cv_img);
cvDestroyWindow("main_win");
```

This code will make the window created by OpenCV borderless, but you still might have to tweak one thing or another to make this operation *perfect*. You'll see why. One idea is to resize the window and make it the size of the image.

**EDIT**:

Well, since you stated:

> writing a demo might be very hard

I also decided to do this last part for you, since I'm such a nice guy =]

This is a small improvement of the code above:

```
HWND win_handle = FindWindow(0, L"main_win");
if (!win_handle)
{
    printf("Failed FindWindow\n");
}

// Resize
unsigned int flags = (SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
flags &= ~SWP_NOSIZE;
unsigned int x = 0;
unsigned int y = 0;
unsigned int w = cv_img->width;
unsigned int h = cv_img->height;
SetWindowPos(win_handle, HWND_NOTOPMOST, x, y, w, h, flags);

// Borderless
SetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_TOPMOST);
ShowWindow(win_handle, SW_SHOW);
```

And on my system it displays exactly what you asked on the question.

Comment: I'll try to write a demo for you and post here in 10 hours.

Comment: Now, whoever down voted my answer please explain why. These were super valid considerations and the OP might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Have you seen how I refrased my question. I found the source of the problem. So writing a demo might be very hard...

Comment: Review my answer, test it, come back here and replace the *down vote* for an *up vote*, and then accept my question. Thank you very much, it was a pleasure.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. You really implemeted and optimized that for me. I think that you have just invested more love and help than I get from my friends :-).

Comment: The nugget "Don't use cvGetWindowHandle and use WinAPI's FindWindow instead" just solved a similar issue I had where I could not get my OpenCV windows to stay always-on-top using WS_EX_TOPMOST.  THANK YOU!

Comment: This method works with images less than monitor resolution. If I have an image with a resolution equal to my monitor, it left a grey bar at the bottom. How to remove that, please?