# OpenCv border top and left OpenGL frame c++

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, border, imshow

I'm using a self compiled of OpenCv 3.3 with OPENGL and CUDA enabled on Windows 7.

I'm having trouble to display an image in fullscreen mode without any border.
I use the following minimal example for my test:

```
// Name of window
std::string name = "Test Window";

// Create window
cv::namedWindow(name, CV_WINDOW_OPENGL | cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvSetWindowProperty(name.c_str(), CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

// Create a frame at resolution
cv::Size size = cv::Size(1920, 1080);  
cv::cuda::GpuMat emptyFrame;
cv::Mat frame(size, CV_8UC(3));

// Fill it in blue
cv::rectangle(frame, cv::Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), CV_FILLED);
emptyFrame.upload(frame);

// Size window to full resolution
cv::resizeWindow(name, size.width, size.height);

while(1)
{
    // Display an empty frame
    cv::imshow(name, emptyFrame);
    cv::waitKey(40);
}
```

This code show me a full screen windows paint in blue, however it remain a ONE pixel border on top and left border:
[Grey left and top border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBq00.png)

The border seem not to be the border as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38494752/1570628

In fact it's the background of the main window created by OpenCv.
Digging into OpenCv code, it effectivelly create 2 windows inside ***cvNamedWindow*** function:

```
mainhWnd = CreateWindow( "Main HighGUI class", name, defStyle | WS_OVERLAPPED, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, 0, 0, hg_hinstance, 0 );
if( !mainhWnd )
CV_ERROR( CV_StsError, "Frame window can not be created" );

ShowWindow(mainhWnd, SW_SHOW);

//YV- remove one border by changing the style
hWnd = CreateWindow("HighGUI class", "", (defStyle & ~WS_SIZEBOX) | WS_CHILD, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, rect.width, rect.height, mainhWnd, 0, hg_hinstance, 0);
if( !hWnd )
CV_ERROR( CV_StsError, "Frame window can not be created" );
```

So the 'border' we saw is the ***mainhWnd*** (Main HighGUI class) color.
However, it mean that my displayed image in blue is shifted by one pixel to the rigth and bottom of my screen, so I loose 1 line of pixel on bottom and right side because they overflow the screen.

I can see that it's the case because on a dual screen I can see the right line of pixel overflow on my second screen. More over, if I draw an horizontal line to the last line of my image, it doesn't appear, same occur on vertical line for last column of my image.

For testing solution, I tried to change style of *mainhWnd* and *hWnd* directly in OpenCv code by using many combination of flags, also testing using WS_POPUP, but anyway I always have this top and left border.

I also tried solution here but it do not remove the border:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6512315/1570628

Do anyone have a clue for my problem?
Regards.

Comment: After some digging, I was unable to found the cause of problem.  

I came accross this Open issue on OpenCv project:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4605

So it seem a long time bug which is not fixed.

For the moment I added freeGlut to my project in order to use it for the OpenGL display part:
http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/

It works perfectly and I have no top and left border. Also I can continue to use OpenCv for manipulate GpuMat.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this worked for me (at least it did on python, and since you just have to change a flag, i believe this will work for you too)

Change this flag "CV_WINDOW_OPENGL | cv::WINDOW_NORMAL)" to this flag "WINDOW_FREERATIO"

And voila! Problem Solved

Comment: I tested it and it always show a grey border.

Moreover I cannot use this because I use OPENGL so I'm stuck with CV_WINDOW_OPENGL.
I need an Opengl Window for display 4K video stream from graphic cards.