# C++ Windows display frameless image

Tags: c++, windows, image

I have an external display and I want to show a borderless/frameless image with exactly the same height and width as the external monitor.
I started out with OpenCV but I had problems getting a borderless image.
After some searching I found this question:

[How to display an image in full screen borderless window in openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512094/how-to-display-an-image-in-full-screen-borderless-window-in-opencv/6512315#6512315)

where karlphillip's answer is of great help.
However, I am stuck at the problem A.k. mentions in his/her comment to the answer:

*This method works with images less than monitor resolution. 
If I have an image with a resolution equal to my monitor, it left a grey bar at the bottom. How to remove that, please?*

Additionally, It seems that the image also has a 1px wide grey bar at the top.
**For my application it is extremely important that every pixel has exactly the value it is supposed to have** and that no pixel is left out
(or overwritten by a grey bar). The image must not be distorted in any way.

I am not looking for a super fast solution but I intend to write images at roughly 10Hz.
Also, I am working on Windows only so the solution doesn't have to be cross-platform.

This is my code, I am working on Windows 10 with VS2019:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {

    // Pixels of external monitor, can be different later
    size_t N_x = 2560; // 1920
    size_t N_y = 1440; // 1080

    // My display resolution. Used to shift the OpenCV image
    size_t disp_width  = 2560;
    size_t disp_height = 1440;

    // To verify that the image is written correctly I generate a sawtooth image with a 4 pixel period.
    byte period = 4;
    byte slope = 110 / (period - 1);
    std::vector<byte> image_vec (N_y * N_x);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N_y; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N_x; j++) {
            image_vec.at(i * N_x + j) = slope * (j % period);
        }
    }

    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(N_y, N_x, CV_8UC1);
    memcpy(image.data, image_vec.data(), image_vec.size() * sizeof(byte));

    // When I use cv::WINDOW_NORMAL instead of cv::WINDOW_FULLSCREEN the image gets distorted in the horizontal direction
    cv::namedWindow("Display Window", cv::WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    imshow("Display Window", image);

    // Grab the image and resize it, code taken from karlphillip's answer
    HWND win_handle = FindWindowA(0, "Display Window");
    if (!win_handle) {
        printf("Could not find window\n");
    }

    // Resize
    unsigned int flags = (SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    flags &= ~SWP_NOSIZE;
    unsigned int x = 0;
    unsigned int y = 0;
    unsigned int w = image.cols;
    unsigned int h = image.rows;
    SetWindowPos(win_handle, HWND_NOTOPMOST, x, y, w, h, flags);

    // Borderless
    SetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(win_handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_TOPMOST);
    ShowWindow(win_handle, SW_SHOW);

    cv::waitKey(0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at UWP but this is not what I want for my application. In the end I chose to use OpenGL/FreeGLUT which works well after some trial and error. If someone is interested I can write a more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the image in an app (that you can also write) and set the app to full screen mode using the `ApplicationView` class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView?redirectedfrom=MSDN. Example code is in https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FullScreenMode

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryenterfullscreenmode This approach is based on UWP so you may get problems using it on earlier versions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have a look at it although I would prefer a solution/fix using the standard Win32 API.